# Kafka Snowflake Connector: org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

Worker Node distributed-connector log:

```
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,605] WARN The configuration 'config.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'rest.advertised.host.name' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'status.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'group.id' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'rest.host.name' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'rest.advertised.port' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'plugin.path' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'config.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known config.    (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'offset.flush.interval.ms' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'rest.port' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'key.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'status.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'offset.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'topic' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,606] WARN The configuration 'offset.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,607] WARN The configuration 'value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,607] WARN The configuration 'key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:362)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,607] INFO Kafka version: 2.6.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:117)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,607] INFO Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:118)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,607] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1637658322607 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:119)
[2021-11-23 09:05:22,991] INFO Kafka cluster ID: zojXCfzxQum_fc3mC6WN_A (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils:65)
[2021-11-23 09:05:23,008] INFO Logging initialized @10836ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log:169)
[2021-11-23 09:05:23,076] INFO Added connector for http://**masternodename**:8083 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:132)
[2021-11-23 09:05:23,076] INFO Initializing REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:204)
[2021-11-23 09:05:23,083] INFO jetty-9.4.24.v20191120; built: 2019-11-20T21:37:49.771Z; git: 363d5f2df3a8a28de40604320230664b9c793c16; jvm 1.8.0_192-BellSoft-b12 (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:359)
[2021-11-23 09:05:23,120] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:84)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unable to initialize REST server
    at   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeServer(RestServer.java:216)
    at   org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to MasterServerName/MasterIP:8083
    at   org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.initializeServer(RestServer.java:214)
    ... 2 more
      Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
    ... 9 more
```

**Master Node: Server.log:**

```
[2021-11-23 09:23:04,041] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=0] Unexpected error from    /**workernode-ip**; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = -720899)
        at   org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:103)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:913)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:816)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [2021-11-23 09:30:35,461] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
```

Comment: workder-node>>server.properties:
listeners=PLAINTEXT://MasterServerName:9093
broker.id=1
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=MasterNode:2181,workder-node1:2181,workder-node2:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

Comment: worker-node>>connect-distributed.properties
bootstrap.servers=worknode-ip:9092,localhost:9092,masternode-ip:9092
group.id=connect-cluster
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
#offset.storage.partitions=25
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
rest.advertised.host.name=MasterServerName
rest.advertised.port=9092
plugin.path=/opt/Kafka/kafka/libs/
topic=uat.product.topic

Comment: masternode-ip>>server.properties
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://workder-node-name:9092
num.network.threads=3

Comment: masternode-server>>connect-distributed.properties
bootstrap.servers=masternode-ip:9092,workernode-ip:9092,workernode-ip:9092
group.id=connect-cluster
rest.host.name=masternode-ip.ec2.internal
rest.port=8083
rest.advertised.host.name=MasterServerNamerest.advertised.port=9092
plugin.path=/opt/Kafka/kafka/libs/

Comment: It is difficult to tell what you're asking. Please do not use comments to add logs and properties

Answer (score 0):

A BindException means you have some networking properties misconfigured, or there is already something running on conflicting ports. For example - `bootstrap.servers=...localhost:9092...` and `rest.advertised.port=9092` would indicate you have Kafka broker already running on port 9092 and trying to make Kafka Connect start an HTTP server on that same port, which will not work.

Regarding the other issues I can see

1. `server.properties` > `listeners` should always be `0.0.0.0` for a host/ip, not the machine hostname if you want external clients to that machine.
2. If possible, don't run Kafka Connect on the brokers, so `localhost:9092` should never be added to `bootstrap.servers` of `connect-distriubuted.properties`
3. `connect-distributed.properties` > `rest.advertised.port` should not be 9092 since it is **not a broker**. The default of 8083 is fine...
4. You should start with one broker and one Connect worker on separate hosts. If you don't have access to multiple physical machines, using Docker-Compose rather than VMs would be simplest.

I suspect these last two are your error because Connect is trying to use the Kafka TCP protocol on itself, so the "Invalid receive" refers to the bytes in the request/response. Then to correctly setup a Kafka cluster and clients, then `listeners` should not be just the hostname of the local machine of the process; this is what `advertised.listeners` on the brokers are for

Comment: created distributed services with worker node, there is no proper guide. Where what should be the parameters for cluster based implementation for 1 Server and 2 nodes. How the server.properties, distributed-connector.properties, zookeeper.properties needs to be configured should be in generic. Including any best practices. Please guide.As the ports, ips, server names really confused.

Comment: There is a guide, though. The documentation states that the `group.id` & `bootstrap.servers` & 3 internal topics are the five properties that must be the same to create a Connect cluster. - _in addition to the common settings mentioned above, are critical to set before starting your cluster_ - http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect

Comment: The 4th point, how it can be achieved on AWS EC2 Machines? For the point 3rd: bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 is given for standalone, what about the cluster master and worker nodes. For 2nd point, we need to have all the IPs instead of the localhost right?

Comment: Overall, I'd suggest using Ansible (https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-ansible) or Kubernetes (via Strimzi) to setup a cluster

Comment: I'd recommend not using EC2 and rather using MSK if the goal is to just get it working